# In eclipse executing Sass with ANT task. Why have I to set 'executable' to 'sass.bat' instead of 'sass'?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, batch-file, ant, sass

I have this ANT task to execute Sass in an eclipse project:

```
<project basedir="." default="sass">
    <target name="sass">
        <apply dest="www/styles" executable="sass">
            <srcfile/>
            <targetfile/>
            <fileset dir="styles" includes="*.scss"/>
            <mapper from="*.scss" to="*.css" type="glob"/>
        </apply>
    </target>
</project>
```

It works fine in Ubuntu. In Windows 7 I have to set the executable as `sass.bat`.

This is the error:

```
Buildfile: D:\my_workspace\my_project\build.xml

sass:

BUILD FAILED
D:\my_workspace\my_project\build.xml:3: Execute failed: java.io.IOException:
Cannot run program "sass" (in directory "D:\my_workspace\my_project"):
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Total time: 326 milliseconds
```

Both, sass and sass.bat can be invoked from the command line so as the `Ruby/bin` folder is in system `PATH` variable.

I don't want to mantain two versions of this file for different OS.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved it by adding the conditional variable `exec_file` with value `sass.bat` for Windows family OS and `sass` for other.

```
<project basedir="." default="sass">
    <condition property="exec_file" value="sass.bat" else="sass" >
        <os family="windows" />
    </condition>

    <target name="sass">
        <apply dest="www/styles" executable="${exec_file}">
            <srcfile/>
            <targetfile/>
            <fileset dir="styles" includes="*.scss"/>
            <mapper from="*.scss" to="*.css" type="glob"/>
        </apply>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: While this solves your problem, it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

[not an answer-but too big for comment ]

Windows shell understand how to expand pathext.  Ant does not interpret - it only try .exe, not others.

[See comments for Windows Users](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

> The  task delegates to Runtime.exec which in turn apparently
>   calls ::CreateProcess. It is the latter Win32 function that defines
>   the exact semantics of the call. In particular, if you do not put a
>   file extension on the executable, only ".EXE" files are looked for,
>   not ".COM", ".CMD" or other file types listed in the environment
>   variable PATHEXT. That is only used by the shell.
>
> Note that .bat files cannot in general by executed directly. One
>   normally needs to execute the command shell executable cmd using the
>   /c switch.
>
> A common problem is not having the executable on the PATH. In case you get an error message
>   Cannot run program "...":CreateProcess error=2. The system cannot find
>   the path specified. have a look at your PATH variable. Just type the
>   command directly on the command line and if Windows finds it, Ant
>   should do it too. (Otherwise ask on the user mailinglist for help.) If
>   Windows can not execute the program add the directory of the program
>   to the PATH (set PATH=%PATH%;dirOfProgram) or specify the absolute
>   path in the executable attribute in your buildfile.

Comment: I forgot to comment that your 'not an answer' guided me to my answer. Thank you very much.